# Google Tag Manager find event

Tags: google-tag-manager

Using Google Tag Manager (GTM) we track multiple events on our website. This works fine, however one event is tracked in Google Analytics for which we cannot find any reference in GTM. In Tag Assistant we see the event is called. But as said, we cannot find the settings for this event anywhere in GTM. Below, a picture of the event being called. [image]

Because we couldn't find this event name in GTM we thought it might be set manually on the webpage. However, there is no reference to this event name in any of web documents.

How can we find the trigger for this event in Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing things up.

Your screenshot looks like your rogue event is a DL push. DL pushes are rarely invoked from GTM and calling it from GTM is a mistake or a hack in vast majority of cases.

DL events are meant to be used as a means to communicating callbacks firing to GTM. DL is commonly used by third party plug-ins and extensions to make them trackable.

Now, you're saying that you see the event in GA. This implies that either GTM does in fact listen to it, or that it bypesses GTM, which is a flaw if it does.

Install adswerve's DL inspector. Open the console. Go to the page that causes this event to fire and make it fire. See the GA event reported in the console by the extension.

Now open your devtools drawer, and open the request blocking feature there. Enable it and add `gtm` to the block list. Reload the page, re-invoke the event. Do you see it still?

Now if you do see it, then it's likely that you're loading gtag.js separately from GTM, and gtag takes care of sending the event independently from GTM. Remove the load of gtag.js. GTM is perfectly capable of loading libraries it needs to conduct tracking.

If you don't see the the event firing, it means that GTM indeed is the one to blame. Download the json export of your container and look for the event name there. If you don't find it, then you will have to manually go through all your triggers of the custom event type and find the ones that use regular expressions for event names. One of them might be triggering on your event.

Comment: The DL push is invoked from within GTM. The JSON export does not contain the name of the event tracked in GA. I already checked all triggers manually but still could not find it. Your answer was very helpful though.

Comment: then go to GTM preview, trigger the event, see what tag sends your event, click the tag in the debugger and see what trigger fired.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested. It was a custom event created in Google Analytics not in Google Tag Manager. You can find custome events in GA under admin --> choose the right property --> click Events --> click Create events. Now you will see all custom events. More on this subject can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10085872?hl=en&utm_id=ad#zippy=%2Ccreate-an-event-from-an-existing-event